# Disable confirmation for LVM in preseed file?

Tags: preseed

I'm not sure which debconf option should I use to bypass this disk change confirmation:

[image]

And does the order of debconf commands matters ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This should do it:](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=610282)

```
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

The order *should* not matter, but I wouldn't do something crazy like rewriting the default recipe from bottom to top :)